# Is each of these one single UTF-8 character?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I want to be able to insert these characters into my clipboard programmatically. Is each of them one single UTF-8 character? If not, what encoding are they in?
I was looking though UTF-8 character table http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl under latin letters but couldn't find them.

Ấ
Ầ
Ẩ
Ẫ
Ậ
Ứ
Ừ
Ử
Ữ
Ự
Ỡ
Ợ
Ở
Ề
Ể
Ễ

Comment: Yes, they all have individual Unicode code points, starting at U+1EA4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character table you linked to in your question covers only the codepoints in Unicode's [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) (U+0000..U+007F) and [Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) (U+0080..U+00FF) blocks.  Each of the characters you have shown are codepoints in Unicode's [Latin Extended Additional](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1E00.pdf) block (U+1E00..U+1EFF).  When encoded in UTF-8, these characters take up 3 bytes each, as follows:

`Ấ` = U+1EA4 = `E1 BA A4`

`Ầ` = U+1EA6 = `E1 BA A6`

`Ẩ` = u+1EA8 = `E1 BA A8`

`Ẫ` = U+1EAA = `E1 BA AA`

`Ậ` = U+1EAC = `E1 BA AC`

`Ứ` = U+1EE8 = `E1 BB A8`

`Ừ` = U+1EEA = `E1 BB AA`

`Ử` = U+1EEC = `E1 BB AC`

`Ữ` = U+1EEE = `E1 BB AE`

`Ự` = U+1EF0 = `E1 BB B0`

`Ỡ` = U+1EE0 = `E1 BB A0`

`Ợ` = U+1EE2 = `E1 BB A2`

`Ở` = U+1EDE = `E1 BB 9E`

`Ề` = U+1EC0 = `E1 BB 80`

`Ể` = U+1EC2 = `E1 BB 82`

`Ễ` = U+1EC4 = `E1 BB 84`

Depending on your platform, you may or may not be able to store UTF-8 on the clipboard.  For instance, on Windows, you can store text only as ANSI or UTF-16 (unless you create a custom clipboard format to hold UTF-8).